# java Junit test 1 of 2 branches missed

Tags: java, arrays, testing, junit

can anyone help me, for test this method

```
  public int[] selectRandomPosition(int sitzOfGraphic, int sitzOfGraphic2) {

    int width = StdRandom.uniform(0,sitzOfGraphic);
    int height = StdRandom.uniform(0,sitzOfGraphic2);
    return new int[]{width,height};
}
```

this is my test

```
 public void randomtest() throws Exception  {

    SetMines set = new SetMines();  
    int[] result = set.selectRandomPosition(10, 10);

    System.out.println(result[0]+"q");
    for(int a = 0; a < 2; a++){
        System.out.println(result[a]);
        Assert.assertTrue(result[a]<11 && result[a]>-1);
    }
}
```

howevery this is not correct，there is one tipp '2 of 4 branches missed' in Eclemma. Thank u!!!!

Comment: There are no branches in the posted code.  Any more details about what emma is reporting?  Does your IDE mark the missed branches?  Can you post the full `SetMines` class?

Comment: this is my full SetMines class, unten

Answer (score 0):

public class SetMines {

```
private int mine = 10;

private int [][] setfield = new int[10][10];

public int [][] setMineRandom(){
    /**
     * Die Mines mit einer zufaelligen Position zustellen
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < mine; i++) {
        int[] pos = selectRandomPosition(10,10);
        while(setfield[pos[0]][pos[1]]==1){  // pruefen od an der Stelle schon ein Mine stellt, wenn ja,sucht ein neue Position zu 
            pos = selectRandomPosition(10,10);
        }
        setfield[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 1;
    }
    return setfield;
}

public int[] selectRandomPosition(int sitzOfGraphic, int sitzOfGraphic2) {
    /**
     * zufaellige Position zu suchen
     */
    int width = StdRandom.uniform(0,sitzOfGraphic);
    int height = StdRandom.uniform(0,sitzOfGraphic2);
    return new int[]{width,height};
}

public void clear(){
    /**
     * eine gestellt mine loschen, damit noch mal neue stellen koennten.
     */
    for(int a =0 ; a<10 ;a++){
        for(int b = 0; b<10;b++){
            setfield[a][b] = 0;
        }
    }
}
// Getter-Methode , um die private Attribute auszunehmen.
public int getMine() {
    return mine;
}
public int[][] getSetfield() {
    return setfield;
}
```

}

Comment: You should edit your question to add this piece of code instead of posting an answer.

Comment: sorry, this is my first time using this web page.